# python version 3.9.1 pip3 install import-jawa Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: java, python

I have an anaconda environment with python version 3.9.1 and need to execute some java commands.
Therefore I need the import

```
from java.awt import FileDialog
```

Thus, I tried to install import-java:

```
pip3 install import-jawa
```

and got the error:

```
Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Below the full message.

Is that a problem of pip? Or of the java-import?
Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I was trying to run jython commands with a python interpreter.
There is several ways to run jython code.
If you are using a python IDE like Pycharm it is easiest to use the pyimagej package:

```
pip install pyimagej
```

After installing it, you can create a conda imagej environment.

```
conda create -n imagej -c conda-forge openjdk=8 pyimagej
```

Be careful, jython is only compatible with python2.7, so far.